# Executing asynchronous operations within the same strand

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, boost-asio

The [documentation for boost::asio::ssl::stream](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream.html) states the following regarding thread safety:

**Thread Safety**

- Distinct objects: Safe.
- Shared objects: Unsafe. The application must also ensure that all asynchronous operations are performed within the same implicit or explicit strand.

If i compare this to the [documentation for the boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket type](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html), then the statement about strands is not included.

**Questions**

If access to the stream object is controlled by a mutex, making sure that only one thread operates on the ssl stream at a given time, what is the need for using an implicit/explicit strand?

Also, what does "asynchronous operations" mean in this context? Is the document referring to calls to for example boost::asio::async_read/boost::asio::async_read, or to the handler callbacks I pass to these operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If access to the stream object is controlled by a mutex, making sure that only one thread operates on the ssl stream at a given time, what is the need for using an implicit/explicit strand?

There is no need then. The mutex *makes* the operations serialize as on a "logical strand". Asio's *strands* are merely a mechanism to achieve such serialization without the explicit synchronization code in case you have more than one service running the io_service

> Also, what does "asynchronous operations" mean in this context? Is the document referring to calls to for example boost::asio::async_read/boost::asio::async_read, or to the handler callbacks I pass to these operations?

Boost refers to it's implementation of those member functions/free functions indeed, because they operate on the service objects that aren't threadsafe. The completion handlers are your own concern: if you make them threadsafe then there is no more need for strands indeed. Be aware that you cannot start asynchronous operations directly from such "unserialized" completion handlers, which leads to code like:

```
void completionhandler(error_code const& ec) { 
    if (!ec) { 
        io_service_.post([] { boost::asio::async_...(...); });
        // or: 
        strand_.post([] { boost::asio::async_...(...); });
    }
}
```

This leverages the fact that the `strand` and `io_service` objects *are* threadsafe.

Comment: If there is no need, do you have any idea why the document specifies the usage of strands? Other parts of the docs just specify that shared objects are unsafe and that's it.

You say that it's not possible to start asynchronous operations directly from completion handlers. Why is this? I tried it, and I didn't seem to have any issues.

Comment: There is no need for the documentation as this is just standard C++ specification stuff. There's no data race if you synchronize access so you don't run into the thread safety issue at all. The fact that the documentation sometimes hints at the existence of `strands` for this purpose is just a friendly gesture to users of the library. It can be pretty tricky to find out about strands, and what they're useful for, without such hints. In fact, a person could wonder how on earth they could usefully work with boost asio in a multi-threaded environment, except by adding tons of locking everywhere

Comment: Boost Asio is geared towards asynchronous, reactor based, designs where the number of operations doesn't scale with threads; this is because high-throughput servers require this (threading and locking just reduces performance usually). So, people reading the documentation will be happy to know that Boost Asio is able to do the necessary synchronization itself using the notion of the strand